# When I open a menu in codeblocks' title bar, the new window shows nothing and cannot be closed

Tags: code-blocks

[image: the new window shows nothing]

The problem happens from time to time (it works fine half of the time). I updated my Ubuntu from 16.04 to 16.10, and I have tried to reinstall several times, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting this too... so frustrating. I'd like to be able to use it : / at this point, it's unusable, as every time I go to open a new window, there is a high chance it will be unresponsive and blank.

Comment: When you have sufficient reputation you can post this as a comment. In the meantime please be advised this is not an answer.